# How to sum N columns in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

My data gets updated every month so I'm trying to create a power query table that would show the sum of the pivoted (N) columns that I created but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in power query.

I have this code currently:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- After Pivoting:
- Create a list of the columns to sum
- Add an Index column to restrict to each row
- Add a column which Sums the columns for just that row
- Remove the Index colum

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Month Yr", Date.Type}, {"Attribute", type text}, {"Value", Currency.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "MonthYear", each Date.ToText([Month Yr],"MMMM yyyy")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Month Yr"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[MonthYear]), "MonthYear", "Value", List.Sum),

//NEW code added after your Pivoted Column line

//Get List of columns to sum
//  Assumes this list all columns **except the first** in the Pivot table
//  There are other methods of generating this list if this assumption is incorrect
colToSum = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"),1),

//Add Index Column
IDX = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Pivoted Column","Index",0,1),

//Sum each row of "colToSum"
totals = Table.AddColumn(IDX, "Sum", each List.Sum(
        Record.ToList(
            Table.SelectColumns(IDX,colToSum){[Index]})
    ), Currency.Type),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(totals,{"Index"})


in
#"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Comment: Do i have to hard code this part? "Add a column which Sums the columns for just that row"

Comment: @ZyreSoriano What do you mean by "hard code"? That usually refers to creating, for example, a constant with the value of a Column Name.  I don't do any of that.  If you mean *can that code be entered from the User Interface?*, then the answer is no. You have to enter it using the `Advanced Editor` (from the Home tab).  If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: @ZyreSoriano Or maybe you missed seeing this line of code below the comments explaining what that line does? `colToSum = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"),1),`?

Comment: I understand how the code works now, I am now able to replicate the steps using my actual file:D

Answer (score 0):

You can group and then merge into the table after pivoting

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Atribute"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Month Year", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Month Year", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Month Year"]), "Month Year", "Value", List.Sum),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Pivoted Column",{"Atribute"}, #"Grouped Rows",{"Atribute"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Sum"}, {"Sum"})
in #"Expanded Table"
```

Or you can group, add it to the table, then pivot the combined new set

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Atribute"}, {{"Value", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Month Year", each "Sum"),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Month Year", "Atribute", "Value"}),
combined = #"Reordered Columns" & #"Changed Type",
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(combined, {{"Month Year", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(combined, {{"Month Year", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Month Year"]), "Month Year", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```