# COUNTIFS Equivalent for PowerQuery in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have table which is the result of three separate queries which haven been appended. I would like to create a custom column in Power query which counts the number of say "Nein" in each row etc.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ron Rosenfeld's, answer here [How to Sum N columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312962/how-to-sum-n-columns-in-power-query/67316555) modified slightly does the job

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
ColToCheck = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
totals = Table.AddColumn( #"Added Index", "Count", each List.Count(Text.PositionOf(Text.Combine(Record.ToList(Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Index",ColToCheck){[Index]}),":")&":","Nein:",Occurrence.All ))),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(totals,{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```